# Codeignitier how edit data from Database using MVC if query using "As" on table

Tags: database, codeigniter, edit, using

Need Help... 
in my database slq server im using command

```
select a.data1, c.data1 as Nama1, d.data1 as Nama2, b.data1 as Nama3, a.subTotal as SubTotal from Tabel1 a inner join Tabel2 b on a.data1 = b.kode inner join Tabel2 c on b.kode = c.kode inner join Tabel3 d on a.kode = d.kode where b.kode = 2 order by c.data1, d.data1, b.data1
```

and my javascript im using command

```
//Ajax Load data from ajax
function edit_room(Kode)
{
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('room/ajax_edit')?>/" + Kode,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            $('[name="Kode"]').val(data.Kode);
            $('[name="Nama1"]').val(data.Nama1);
            $('[name="Nama2"]').val(data.Nama2);
            $('[name="Nama3"]').val(data.Nama3);

            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('FORM EDIT Room'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

},
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
}
```

but why i cant edit Nama1, nama2 and nama3

there any expert can help me

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking of editing in ajax success method? If so then you have to use the same name what you have given in your query or creating your response array to ajax call in controller.

Comment: yes been trying to use the same name but still not show

            $('[name="Nama1"]').val(data.Nama1);
            $('[name="Nama2"]').val(data.Nama2);
            $('[name="Nama3"]').val(data.Nama3);

Comment: Did you printed the response in controller to check its not empty?

Comment: for a.data1 it show but for c.data1 as Nama1 the Nama1 not show
so i think the problem if the sql command using "as" cannot show in edit form

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. To make sure, remove aliases from your query and try to print in controller.

Comment: if i remove alias how to distinguish c.data1 as Nama1, d.data1 as Nama2, b.data1 as Nama3 cause field name table have same name

Comment: fieldname will come as c.data1,d.data1,b.data1 respectively.

Comment: how to display in array? if name=c.data1 etc

Comment: As you do normally, `$arr['c.data1']`.